# SQL Server concat/join different words in a string to get all substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join words in a sentence in SQL server.  I need it to loop through using the next word as the sgtarting word to concat each time.  For example the string/sentence could be 'This is a sentence'.

I need the possible outcomes to be:

```
This
Thisis
Thisisa
Thisisasentence
is
isa
isasentence
a
asentence
sentence
```

I know how to concat but I'm not too sure how I would go about doing each word with differet first word each time.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
More information as requested.

I have a table `Account(IS(PK), Name, Country)`

I have another table `accountSubstrings(SubID(pk), AccountID, Substring)`

I need to break the 'Name' column into the above example 'This is a sentence' so that each substring has its own row entry in accountSubstrings.  The subID is unique to each row and the AccountID will map to whichever 'Name' the substring came from.  This is being done for matching purposes.

Thanks

Comment: if you could provide your sample data and table structure with logic that will be helpful

Comment: @Avi I have edited and added more info, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a recursive CTE.  Basically, you want adjacent combinations.  I prefer to put spaces between the words, so they are visible.  The following also assumes that the words are unique:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = 'This is a sentence';

with words as (
      select s.value as word, row_number() over (order by charindex(s.value, @s)) as seqnum
      from string_split(@s, ' ') s
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, word as combined, format(seqnum, '000') as seqnums
      from words
      union all
      select w.seqnum, concat(cte.combined, ' ', w.word), concat(seqnums, ':', format(w.seqnum, '000'))
      from cte join
           words w
           on w.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
order by seqnums;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=519cace67dcd3cf551a47c0c1d040bc2) is a db<>fiddle.

The actually tricky part here is keeping the words in order.  That is what the `row_number()` is doing, capturing the order -- and where the uniqueness restriction comes from.  Of course, this could be replaced by a recursive CTE, and that would be fine (and allow duplicate words).

Comment: how would I change this to be a function as I want to do this to go through all rows in my Account Table and inserting the substrings as new rows in to the accountsubstring table? Also it would only return the 'Combined' part as this will be inserted into the accountSubstring table? So it would take in @Name as @s Thanks very much

Comment: @user19902020 . . . That would be a different question.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Comment: I have created a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041341/sql-function-to-split-string-and-concat-substrings)  Thanks very much for your help. Hopefully it is explained better

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the updates you made, you can do as

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('This is a sentence')) T(Name)
JOIN (VALUES('This'), ('is'), ('a'), ('sentence')) TT(SubString)
ON CONCAT(' ', T.Name, ' ') LIKE CONCAT(' %', TT.SubString, ' %');
```

Here the table `T` is your table `Account`, and the table `TT` is your table `accountSubstrings`

Comment: thanks very much but I would need it to return the words concat and itirating through changing the first word until all concats are complete.  I need it to be able to take in a columnas it will need to do all rows in the column 'Name' in the Account table.  The above answer by Gordon works but I am trying to change it to  function but keeps giving me errors

Comment: You already have the words in `Substring` column @user19902020

Comment: it only shows the words, they do not concat, I have ran it, it also only works for the above words but it would need to take in a column.   The sentence 'This is a sentence' was just used as an example of how it should be split/concat.     The below is what your query is giving me:          
    This is a sentence This
    This is a sentence is
    This is a sentence a
    This is a sentence sentence

Comment: Please @user19902020 read and follow [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: was there an issue with my question/explaination?